# JAVA лицензионное соглашение

Tags: java

Как можно предложить пользователю принять лицензионное соглашение, до запуска программы?

Comment: Например на сайте, перед доступом к закачке

Comment: это понятно. а можно ли как-то сделать это в программе, как часто бывает при установке разного софта?

Comment: Взаимоисключающие параграфы вижу я. Нельзя сделать это в программе не запуская ее.

Comment: @Drop как вы сами указали - как часто бывает при _установке_ разного софта - запилите инсталлятор :)

Comment: @rjhdby не верно выразился. имелось ввиду доступ к основному функционалу, после принятия соглашения.@ Alex Chermenin и вправду, че-то я не подумал)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Создать диалоговое окно в javaFX и если соглашение принято, то запустить программу(тут) `startProgram();` если отклонил, то закрывается

```
public void start(Stage dialogStage) throws Exception {
    dialogStage.setWidth(300);
    dialogStage.setHeight(200);
    dialogStage.setTitle("licenze");
    VBox box = new VBox();
    box.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
    HBox buttons = new HBox();
    buttons.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
    Button accept = new Button("yes");
    Button notAccept = new Button("no");
    buttons.getChildren().addAll(accept, notAccept);
    box.getChildren().addAll(new Label("типо лицензия"), buttons);
    Scene scene = new Scene(box);
    dialogStage.setScene(scene);
    dialogStage.show();

    accept.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
            startProgram();
            dialogStage.close();
        }
    });

    notAccept.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
            System.out.println("ok((");
            dialogStage.close;
        }
    });
}
```

Осталось только табуляцию сделать нормально,  и проверить на ошибки (мб опечатался)